# Get values of a form by formControlName, in a non input tag

Tags: angular

Is it possible to get values of a form by formControlName, in a non input tag?

```
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" formControlName="name"/>
```

But what I need is something like this (*a* tag is just an example of a non input tag):

```
<div>
   <label>Name</label>
   <a (click)="someFunction()" formControlName="name"/>
</div>
```

Is it possible in angular?

Comment: What would be the use for that?

Comment: A non-input element has no form input value, so what value do you expect to get?

Comment: @BastianBräu Imagine I have a list of ten names, and I'm showing them as a table list (not  input!), where each item has a delete icon beside.

Comment: That’s not a use case for a form. In your table, you just add buttons with a click handler for deleting a name.

Comment: @BastianBräu yes I know it is not how we use forms normally, but I want to see if it is possible to combine some features! It is just a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A FormGroup exist in the .ts. It's not necessary to have an input.

Really I don't know what do you want . To get a value of a FormControl you can use `your_form.get('name_of_formControl').value`, e.g.

```
<div>
   <label>Name</label>
   <a (click)="someFunction()">{{form.get('name').value}}</a>
</div>
```

Or, e.g. you can change the value

```
<div>
   <label>Name</label>
   <a (click)="form.get('name').setValue('clicked')"/>
</div>
```

Or use a @if

```
<div>
   <label>Name</label>
   @if (!form.get('name').value){
      <a> I'm not name</a>
   }
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo for your reply. Although your solution seems very reasonable and what I'm looking for, it doesn't show the value and returns an error: `Object is possibly 'null'. <a >{{form.get("name").value}}</a> highlighting value`. I added how I have defined my form, maybe the problem is somewhere in my form!

Comment: try using `?`: `{{form.get("name")?.value}}`

Comment: Yes  `{{form.get("name")?.value}} ` Works! Thank you.